# Are there any good libraries for visually creating simple Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api, google

I'm working on a simple webapp that lets the journalists I work with easily construct styled Google maps.

In short, I need an interface that lets users place markers, set zoomlevel and choose a center lat/long — all without writing any JavaScript.

I know Google Maps has a "My Maps" functionality that provides this already, but I'm needing that kind of functionality as a way of adding data to my app.

[image: Something like this...]
*Something like this...*

Anyone know of such a library? I'm currently using a series of text fields using [LocationPicker](https://code.google.com/p/locationpicker/) for the markers, but I still need to be able to set center and zoom — and I can't shake the feeling there's probably already something out there that does this...

Thanks!

**Edit:** This seems close, if a little clunky... http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

Comment: May be helpful for you http://www.cartologic.com/cartoview/ClExtensionsManager/ExtensionDetails.aspx?mid=6&pageid=5&extensionid=19

Comment: @Sunil That doesn't seem to have any editor functionality built in...

Comment: If [this](http://www.screencast.com/t/7CM6cZjP4A) is something you're interested in working off of let me know and I'll upload everything to GitHub for you.

Answer (score 4):

What you are requiring sounds like **Map Channels (v4) or MapFab**

It's Simple you sign up and load your data from Google Spreadsheets in and you can edit/filter data. This does not edit data directly with the map.

http://www.mapchannels.com/MC4Demo.aspx

[image]

If you want edit data directly on the map I suggest: **MapFab**

[image]
http://www.mapfab.com/editor/new

(both use google ads to generate the income.)

Comment: Map Channels looks closer (You can download the source and use it locally), though the ideal solution I'm envisioning generates coordinates within the browser (thus making them available to other scripts). MapFab doesn't seem to do that at all...

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are drawing tools built into Google Maps Maps API v3:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools